# Gender-neutral word for patronymic/matronymic

Tags: single-word-requests

According to Wikipedia:

- A patronymic is a name based on the given name of one's father, grandfather or an even-earlier male ancestor.
- A matronymic is a name based on the given name of one's mother, grandmother or an even-earlier female ancestor.

Is there a gender-neutral word for this?

- A ---------- is a name based on the given name of one's parent, grandparent or an even-earlier ancestor.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions.

Comment: This [Untranslatable Words](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/comments/46sldn/untranslatable_words/) Reddit thread says *They mostly seem to have to do with naming, the age system, and family...* In the list of examples it specifically cites **Parentinom** (Estonian? Russian?) and translates it into English (using "scare quotes", 'cos it's not really a valid word) as **parentonymic**. Native Anglophones just call them all **family names**, because we don't care so much about complex genetic / ancestral / historical relationships.

Answer (score 3):

If you want one what hints at is meaning by using the same suffix -- I would suggest "genonymic".  The root is from *genitore*, which means "parent" in Latin. It's where we get our words *generation* and *genetic*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELU.SE. I fixed your italicization for you, check the edit to see how to do it properly.

Comment: A related term would be geronymic, or maybe, gerontonymic; coming from gerontocracy...rule by the elders. It does not however specify rule by elders to whom one is directly related, as would be in a p(m)atrocracy.

Answer (score -2):

### **[Eponym](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/eponymic)**

> **noun**
>
> 1.
>   a person, real or imaginary, from whom something, as a tribe, nation, or place, takes or is said to take its name:
>   *Brut, the supposed grandson of Aeneas, is the eponym of the Britons.*
>   2.
>   a word based on or derived from a person's name.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/eponymic))

or possibly a **[Homonym](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/homonymic)**:

> 2.
>   b. A namesake.

([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/homonymic))

However, most of the other definitions of a homonym are slightly different in meaning, so you might have to qualify it; e.g. "*parental homonym*" or even "*cognomenal homonym*" if you wanted to refer to any sort of relative.

Comment: 'Eponymic' is an adjective only, according to your reference. And 'eponym' isn't used in the ancestral sense. Again, 'homonymic' isn't given as a noun in your other reference, and OP's 'A ---------- is a name based on the given name of one's parent, grandparent or an even earlier ancestor.' clearly requires one.

Answer (score -5):

What about Androgenomic? As in androgenomic lineage?

Comment: This is a wrong answer. *Genome* is gender neutral, but *androgenome* and *gynogenome* are gender specific. The derived form *androgenomic* given as the answer refers specifically to the male parent.